# Why does reading a device require admin permissions?

Tags: permissions, security, devices, storage

I'm trying to create a backup script that saves my thumbdrive as an image. I'm planning on having it automatic. I've always seen the thumbdrive listed as `/dev/sdb`, and created a script that will save it as a gzipped tarball.

While trying to make a copy of it via `dd`, I noticed this error:

```
dd: failed to open ‘/dev/sdb’: Permission denied
```

I wondered if it was just a fluke, so I tried piping a `cat` command to `dd` and got this error instead:

```
cat: /dev/sdb: Permission denied
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 0.000620078 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

Of course, since I'm a superuser, I can `sudo` it out -- but that removes an element of the script being automatic.

Why does this device need to have superuser permission if I'm not modifying it? Furthermore, is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: Can you just cat a device like that? I'm not sure. I'd mount the device in some location first(which can be automated with fstab (or possibly udev)) and then do the make backup.

Comment: Bibek_G, yes you can use dd to create a backup of a block device and restore it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does reading a device require admin permissions?

Firstly there are couple of issues here

1. `mount`'ing the physical storage device and the partitions it contains.
2. Accessing and manipulating the files on it.

If the filesystem is permissions based, e.g. ext2,3,4 then permissions are defined on a per file basis.

In terms of why you would require the user to have special admin privileges to mount a device there are a few reasons, which are more likely to apply to enterprise type situations and less likely to apply to personal computing - although it still can be relevant

1. **It prevents reading in abusive programs**
   Once a disk is mounted an entire collection of untrusted programs are now potentially available for execution which can abuse the operating system. If you were administering that system, you could be more confident that wouldn't happen if casual users couldn't upload their own programs off their own disks.
2. **Writing / saving sensitive secret data**
   If you had corporate secrets, or users passwords on a system, and someone could connect an unauthorised storage device they can make copies to it.

You can get around the sudo issue by either running the entire script as sudo, and then using `sudo` to switch back to an ordinary user inside the script for the commands you dont want to run as root (yes you *can* do that)  e.g.

*file:* script.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

# this dd command now works
dd if=<source> of=<target> bs=<byte size>

# normal cammand you want to run as "mathmaniac" user
sudo -u "MathManiac" bash -c "touch foo.bar"
```

So you then run this script with:

```
sudo ./script.sh
```

Another quick and dirty but generally not recommended way is simply to put sudo in front of the command inside the script, when the interpreter encounters the `sudo` it will halt script execution and ask you for your sudo password before continuing.

Comment: Out of all the answers I read, this has the most extensive explanation why I need su perms and a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Unix/Linux systems are multi-user. Anyone who has read access to a raw storage device can read all the files on it, regardless of who owns the files and their permissions (modulo the filesystem being encrypted, of course). So traditionally the raw devices have only allowed access to `root` and to members of an administrative group such as `operator` or `disk`, and you'd put your trusted admin users or backup operations users into that group.

On GNU/Linux distributions that run udev, `50-udev-default.rules` puts all block and SCSI devices in `/dev` that are not floppies or tapes in the `disk` group and gives the group read/write permission, so one possible solution for you is to add yourself to that group using `usermod` or by editing `/etc/group` directly. Logout and login again.

Comment: This can be confirmed for the op, but just doing `ls -l /dev/sdb` which will probably show something like `brw-rw---T  1 root disk      8,  16 Feb 25 21:13 sdb` - so as you say, only root and the disk group have access.

Answer (score 0):

You could use edit the fstab to mount the filesystem without being root but that doesn't give you an image of the block device.

You could edit the sudoers file so the backup script can sudo a specific command without entering a password.